# DraftJS WYSIWYG - Cannot Load Content Into Component

Tags: reactjs, draftjs, react-draft-wysiwyg

I'm trying to load a DraftJS WYSIWYG `Editor` component as an already-populated text field with the following: `<p>Hello World</p>`.

```
export default class RichTextComponent extends Component {
  
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      const contentState = convertFromHTML('<p>Hello World</p>')
      const editorState = EditorState.createWithContent(contentState)
  
      this.state = {
        contentState,
        editorState
      }
    }

    render() {
        const { editorState } = this.state
        return <Editor editorState={editorState} />
      }
}
```

But when the component is rendered, I get the following error:

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: invalid RawDraftContentState

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to achieve desired result is:

```
import htmlToDraft from 'html-to-draftjs';

export default class RichTextComponent extends Component {
  
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        const contentBlocks = htmlToDraft('<p>Hello World</p>')
        const contentState = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(contentBlocks)
        const editorState = EditorState.createWithContent(contentState)
    
        this.state = {
          editorState
        }
      }

    render() {
        const { editorState } = this.state
        return <Editor editorState={editorState} />
      }
}
```